# Why is tab-width reset when I open a C++ file?

Tags: init-file, indentation

So I'm trying to setup default indentation in Emacs. Currently I have the following at the bottom of my `.emacs` file as per a number of tutorials I've found on the internet.

```el
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq tab-width 3)
(defvaralias 'c-basic-offset 'tab-width)
(defvaralias 'cperl-ident-level 'tab-width)
(defvaralias 'js-indent-level 'tab-width)
```

Except... it doesn't work; when I open a C++ code file, tab-width appears to be set to 8. Can someone tell me *why* this is, and also what I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Check the docstring. `<f1> v tab-width RET`

Comment: I did, it wasn't helpful

Comment: `Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.` should be your clue

Comment: Yes I read that, but I don't really understand how that causes this problem. Assume I'm a relative newbie

Comment: Ok, never mind, I get it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, turns out the answer to my question was the following:

`tab-width` automatically becomes buffer local when set. The buffer local version derives from the default value, so I needed to use `setq-default` not `setq`

Comment: Note that you could also set the `tab-width` by mode in the mode hook, in case you want different tab widths across different languages.